# Using R32bit from PowerBI

Tags: r, powerbi, 32bit-64bit

I am using PowerBI for report server (64bit), and I need to access information in a 32bit ODBC database. I want to use an R Script to do this, but I have not been able to find the way of indicating PowerBI to use my 32bit R to do this, as it autoimatically chooses the 64bit R I have installed.

How can I indicate to PowerBI that it should use a 32Bit R installation instead of a 64bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R data sources don't support refresh in Power BI Report Server.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/data-sources

For Power BI Desktop you configure the R home directory and it will run whatever you install there.